# Java Exception error (Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException)

Tags: java

This Java class to read data from log file and insert the values in Array list, the data could be changed from int to any other type,,, 
when i run the class in some cases i got this exception error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at GetStaisticResults.readfile(GetStaisticResults.java:33)
    at GetStaisticResults.main(GetStaisticResults.java:15)
```

I tried to cast the values before inserting in the array list in different ways but no results, any help?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class GetStaisticResults {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String inputFile = ("C:\\staticalData.log");
        ArrayList<Integer> Data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Data = readfile(inputFile);//line 15
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> readfile(String file) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file));
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            list.add(s.nextInt()); //line 33
        }
        s.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share content of your file? As code is working file for integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code seems like your input is not `Integer` based. `s.hasNext()` checks for input that could be cast to `String`. You probably should use `s.hasNextInt()` here. Or you could change the `s.nextInt()` to `s.next()` it will take input as a `String`. I am providing two possible solutions, then you can decide which one fulfills your requirements.

**Solution 1:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(s.nextInt());
}
```

In this solution, your code will only take `Integer` as input. Because `s.hasNextInt()` restricts the input to `Integer` value. If it encounters anything other than the `Integer` value then the `while` loop will exit.

**Solution 2:**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNext()) {
    list.add(s.next());
}
```

In this solution, your code will take `String` as input. It won't fail whether your input contains `"abc"` or `7` or `33.32` etc. It will save all of them as a `String` value.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that whenever u read anything from file it is in `string` format 
next inside loop you are taking values for integer while the input is string that's why it's giving  `InputMismatchException`